# Can a wordpress site be salvaged

Tags: wordpress

Firstly I know very little about most of this.  I have looked for answers, but must not be asking the correct questions.

I wanted to redevelop a WordPress site that I have and to do so, installed MAMP in order to do this locally, and allow the current site to remain live. That all went surprisingly well.  Until I had to reboot the machine and I encountered the seeming ubiquitous **MySql Server Won't Start problem**   Much research was done and I found (on this site, which is why I am asking this here)  the answer to that was removing two particular files.

Then it all went down hill and my site is FUBAR.  The database is gone, but I have all the content.

My question is, can I resurrect the site with that data and not have to start. from. scratch.

Cheers

Craig

Comment: Check to see if your hosting has any backups. Most installs have automatic backups these days. If not, run your website through the [Internet archive](https://archive.org/web/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have installed this locally using MAMP, so the only copy of everything is what is on my machine. I have the content, but not the database.  Trying to see if I can resurrect the site from that on my local machine.

Comment: This may or may not help 
[How to restore a MySQL database from your Time Machine backup](http://suburbia.org.uk/blog/2009/05/08/173824.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately - I have no copy of the database - only the WordPress content - I will keep this in mind for my next screw up though!